# Excel VBA Macro - Print to CSV adds blank spaces, trim or other solution?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm currently making a VBA Macro to print a column to a csv file but I'm having an issue where it for some reason adds a bunch of blank spaces on each row.

This is outside what I normally do so I only got this far by reading here. This is the code that I managed to piece together, but with the unfortunate blank spaces added.

```vb
'object to use as folder
Dim fld As Object
Set fld = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim myFile As Object
Set myFile = fld.CreateTextFile("C:\path\filename.csv", True)
 
End Sub

Sub data_to_text_file()

'variables
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim cVal As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim myFile As String
Dim myRange As Range, lr As Long

'defines range

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lr)

iCol = myRange.Count

'path to the text file
myFile = "C:\path\filename.csv"

'define FreeFile to the variable file number
TextFile = FreeFile

'using append command to add text to the end of the file
Open myFile For Output As TextFile

'loop to add data to the text file
For i = 1 To iCol
Print #TextFile, Cells(i, 1),
Print #TextFile, Cells(i, 2)
Next i

'close command to close the text file after adding data
Close #TextFile

End Sub
```

I was trying to add a Trim but never got it working, I think maybe because it's printing to a new file I had issues with locating the cells maybe?

Any suggestions for either stopping the blank spaces to be added on the end of each row, or how to trim?

Comment: Do you have data in column B? If not, that's why you are seeing blanks.

Comment: Only data in column A, but why is B column affecting it? I thought I only specified my range as A?

Comment: Because you are using `Print #TextFile, Cells(i, 2)` which is printing column B.

Comment: Ah, I thought that was making the new row... Without it everything gets on the same row

Comment: Remove the comma from the end of the first `Print` line